# The approximate probability with zero percent sample

Tags: probability, statistics

I just got a statistic question which make me confuse because too many same variable(in this case 10%), so I don't know what is that value and how to  compute the
approximate probability.

Here is the question(I changed the variable values and name, so I could be able to answer the real question by myself):

> A teacher is studying uneducated rate, which is reported to be around
> 10%. He took a random sample of 30 children and found that all of them
> were educated. To help determine if this result is reasonable given a
> 10% uneducated rate, compute the approximate probability that the
> teacher would see this result if the uneducated rate was actually 10%.

I don't know why the sample of 30 children can give a 0% rate.

I tried to research again using a search engine and never found a similar question to this question.

Can anyone help me with a formula for that question?

Comment: I totally forgot what to do because the last time I studied statistics was more than 6 years ago at school. But I think at school I had the correct answer to a question like that because the evaluation was an open book and there was a book with a similar question and answer.

Comment: I don't understand your confusion.  Low probability events can happen.  If the probability that a randomly selected student is uneducated is actually $.1$ then the probability that everyone out of $30$ is educated is $\left(\frac 9{10}\right)^{30}\approx .042$

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand about statistic, where came from 9/10?

Comment: This is just a Bernoulli trial with p(educated) = 0.9, n=30 trials, and k=30 successes.

Comment: If there is a $10\%=\frac 1{10}$ probability that a student is uneducated then there must be a $90\%=.9=1-.1$ probability that the student is educated.

Comment: @lulu Oh I see, 90% is educated children. then what the relation to the question `compute the approximate probability that the teacher would see this result if the uneducated rate was actually 10%.`?   so it means `.042` is the answer of that question?

Comment: Yes, $.042$ is the (approximate) answer.

Comment: OMG, thanks your very much, I didn't expect that just a very simple answer that made me confused in a whole day.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question here and accept it, so that the question does not remain on the unanswered queue.

Comment: To repeat @lulu's comments in a different way: if $X$ is the number of educated students in a random sample of $n=30$ with replacement (or from a very large population) then $X \sim\mathsf{Binom}(30, 0.9)$ so that $P(X=30)$ can be found in R with code `dbinom(30, 30, 0.9)` which returns $ 0.04239116.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lulu answered in the commment:

$\frac{9}{10}^{30} = 0.42$

and BruceET also give additional information:

> if  is the number of educated students in a random sample of =30
> with replacement (or from a very large population) then
> ∼(30,0.9)  so that (=30)  can be found in R with code
> `dbinom(30, 30, 0.9)` which returns 0.04239116

I tried on R online compiler and it worked.
Here is the demo:

https://onecompiler.com/r/3xrtuaq5n

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).